# MacOS C Inconsistent behavior

Tags: c

I have a very weird stuff going on on MacOS, I am working on a simple non-dynamic vector struct and whenever I try to print it, I get a very wrong result. I did ran the same thing on a linux machine and I had zero issues

```
#include "Vector.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

#define VECTOR_SIZE 4

typedef struct _dVec{
    uint32_t len;
    float *_val;
}_dVec;

//Create vector mem
Vector vecinit(int lenght){
    
    //Allocate and init vector
    Vector _vec = malloc(VECTOR_SIZE + sizeof(float) * lenght);
    _vec->len = lenght;
    _vec->_val = (float *) _vec + 4;
    
    return _vec;
}


//Insert a index
void vec_inat(Vector vector, int index, float value){
    vector->_val[index] = value;
}

//Return  from index
float vec_outat(Vector vector, int index){
    return vector->_val[index];
}

int veclen(Vector vector){
    return vector->len;
}

float *vecptr(Vector vector){
    return vector->_val;
}

void vecdeinit(Vector vector){
    if(vector){
        free(vector);
    }
}
```

Vector.h

```
#ifndef Vector_h
#define Vector_h

typedef struct _dVec *Vector;


//Create vector mem
Vector vecinit(int length);

//Insert a index
void vec_inat(Vector vector, int index, float value);

//Return  from index
float vec_outat(Vector vector, int index);

//Vector Length
int veclen(Vector vector);

//Pointer to data
float *vecptr(Vector vector);

//deinit
void vecdeinit(Vector vector);

#endif /* Vector_h */
```

As you can see the expected output is

```
0.300000
0.600000
0.600000
0.600000
0.600000
0.600000
0.600000
0.600000
0.600000
0.200000
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

But instead I am getting this

```
0.300000
0.600000
0.600000
0.600000
0.600000
0.600000
0.600000
0.600000
0.000000
0.000000
```

The weird things are:

```
1) If I set a breakpoint on the first loop and slowly iterate the desired result is achieved

2) If I set length of a vector higher, I get a desired result
```

I have no idea what is going on. I am running it on macOS Catalina.

main.c

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Vector vec = vecinit(10);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < veclen(vec); i++){
        vec_inat(vec, i, 0.6f);
    }
    
    vec_inat(vec, 0, 0.3f);
    vec_inat(vec, 9, 0.2f);
    
    
    for(int i = 0; i < veclen(vec); i++){
        printf("%f\n", vec_outat(vec, i));
    }
    
    vecdeinit(vec);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the main function ? You never test if the index is lower than length this can be the issue

Comment: You're likely not allocating enough space. What is `sizeof(_dVec)` and `sizeof(float*)`? How does that match up with what you're allocating?

Comment: @pmg it is a forward declaration for a pointer, it compiles the problem is different.

Comment: Pointer arithmetics doesn’t work on byte increments, so that may be an issue. Saying `(float*)_vec + 4` means “4 floats forward” when you probably mean “4 bytes forward”, if I’m not entirely mistaken on the order of handling the casting. This hides the issue that you’d be overwriting the pointer itself if it pointed to where you want it to point...

Comment: @RetiredNinja size of _dVec is 4 bytes + whatever amount of floats I need which is expressed in `VECTOR_SIZE + sizeof(float) * lenght`

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen sami the problem that it doesn't work at all, the problem is that it works sometimes, if I just ran the code multiple times, 3 out of 10 runs will print the right vector

Comment: @AntonStafeyev Yes, maybe because you cause undefined behavior by going out of bounds of allocated memory?

Comment: You're trying to implement a flexible array member in a harder/worse way. As mentioned here, your pointer arithmetic is wrong.

Comment: @CarlNorum Yep, looks like I am overwriting the pointer and cause undefined behavior

Comment: Aside: "lenght" --> "length"..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks like a harder/wrong way to to implement a flexible array member. Just using one correctly, like this:

```
typedef struct _dVec{
    uint32_t len;
    float _val[];
}_dVec;

//Create vector mem
Vector vecinit(int lenght){
    
    //Allocate and init vector
    Vector _vec = malloc(sizeof(_dVec) + lenght * sizeof(float));
    _vec->len = lenght;
    
    return _vec;
}
```

Should solve all your problems. If you're really set on doing it the hard way, just fix allocation:

```
Vector _vec = malloc(sizeof(_dVec) + sizeof(float) * lenght);
```

and your pointer arithmetic:

```
_vec->_val = (float *)(_vec + 1);
```

Comment: float _val[] exactly what I was looking for. it was a a long time I didn't touch C :) thanks man